# How can I better structure a function to target information and effect many different tiles in an app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making this [maths app hex wall game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7syOX.jpg) There are 72 "tiles" that have numbers in them chosen from arrays.  There is also a factor that is chosen at random from an array (1,2,5,10).

When you click on a tile there is a function that looks for the variable in the text box and checks if it can be divided by the factor - if it can a green tile appears and if it cant it makes a red hex appear and fade.

```
public class checker : MonoBehaviour
{


public bool correct = false;
private hexe hexinfo;
private fader2 fadeit;
private bool mFaded = false;
public float Duration = 0.4f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    hexinfo = GameObject.Find("Canvas/tileHolder/AtileR1").GetComponent<hexe>();
    var canva1 = GameObject.Find("Canvas/tileHolder/AtileR1").GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();

    canva1.alpha = 0;


}
public void fade1()
{

 var canvGroup = GameObject.Find("Canvas/tileHolder/AtileR1").GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();

    StartCoroutine(DoFade(canvGroup, canvGroup.alpha, mFaded ? 0 : 1));

}

public IEnumerator DoFade(CanvasGroup canvGroup, float start, float end)
{
    start = 0;
    end = 1;
    float counter = 0f;
    while (counter < Duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        canvGroup.alpha = Mathf.Lerp(start, end, counter / Duration);
        yield return null;
        canvGroup.alpha = 0;

    }
}
public void makesurea1()
{
 if((hexinfo.a1%hexinfo.di1) == 0)
    {
        print("perfect");

        hexinfo.green1.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        fade1();
    }

}
```

So now I am trying to make this code as a separate script for each of the 72 tiles and change the target and the variables?
Is that the way you would do it?
Any other ideas of how to structure this?
Thank you for any and all ideas

Comment: seem legit ;) But please use `Find` as little as possible .. tending to **never** ^^ If really needed store the result e.g. in `Start` and reuse the reference. Even better would be e.g. a `[SerializeField] private hexe hexinfo;` and drag in your according object via the Inspector.

Comment: ok thanks I will try to make this happen!